# Irregular cumulative sum in python

Tags: python, sum

I'm stuck with a problem:

Let's say I have a list of names:

```
list_a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'etc.']
```

I have an initial value:

```
x = 50
```

Then I want for every item in `list_a` that `x` gets increased by 10, so I perform:

```
for i, v in enumerate(list_a):
    a = x + 10 * (i + 1)
    print(a)
```

Which results in an output like this:

```
60, 70, 80, 90, 100, ...
```

But now, what I want is that if any item in `list_a` is equal to `'three'`, that item increase `x` by 50 instead of 10, so the result would be:

```
60, 70, 120, 130, 140, 150, ...
```

Any clue about how to do that??

Comment: What about using an `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `enumerate` and recalculating `a` each iteration, you will probably want to have `a` as a seperate counter initialized outside of the loop that is modified each iteration (incremented by 30 if the value is `"three"` and by 10 otherwise):

```
a = X
for value in list_a:
    if value == "three":
        a += 30
    else:
        a += 10
    print(a)
```

Otherwise, you would have to loop through the entire part of the list you already visited in each iteration to count the elements that are equal to `"three"`.

Again, you could of course also keep *that* value (the number of `"three"`s seen) as a counter outside of the loop (instead of `a`):

```
three_counter = 0
for i, v in enumerate(list_a):
    if v == "three":
        three_counter += 1
    # Add 20 for each "three" instead of 30 because the "three"s are also
    # counted in `i`, which adds an additional 10.
    a = X + (i + 1) * 10 + three_counter * 20 
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @hlt's answer, you can also use a dictionary to store your special-case values, then use `dict.get` to look up the desired increment value, or retrieve a default if no override is defined.

```
a = X
default_increment = 10
increment_map = {'three' : 50}
for value in list_a:
    a += increment_map.get(value, default_increment)
    print(a)
```

An `if` statement is fine for a single special case, but if you start getting more than 2 or 3 conditions, a mapping can help to make things clearer to read.